# How to build a release apk with signature in bazel

Tags: bazel

I can't find any rule about `keystore` in bazel's doc or any parameter about signature in `android_binary`'s parameters. So how can I build a release apk with signature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was asked on [bazel-discuss mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/bazel-discuss/2BPWVRnsiGc), it also contains a solution plus some background.

Comment: Get it! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

for the moment, Bazel does not support signing the apk.
As we can read in the docs:

> `android_binary` creates a `name_unsigned.apk`: An unsigned version of the above file that could be signed with the release keys before release to the public.

This means that you should sign this unsigned apk with [apksigner](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/apksigner.html) using other tools. Take a look at [Build an unsigned APK and sign it manually](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#sign-manually) from the Android documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I wore a quick genrule that will do the signing for you. However, one thing to note is that you won't be able to use `mobile-install` on the output signed APK which is very unfortunate (still looking for a way around it).

```
def signed_android_binray(
        name,
        android_binary,
        keystore,
        alias,
        password):
    """
    This macro signs given android_binary with the given keystore

    Example usage:
        load("//bzl:apksigner.bzl","signed_android_binray")

        signed_android_binray(
            name = "signed-foo-app",
            android_binary = ":foo-app",
            keystore = "//path/to/keystore:my-keystore",
            alias = mykeystore,
            pass = foo123,
        )
    """

    unsigned_android_binary = android_binary + "_unsigned.apk"
    output_name = "{}_signed.apk".format(name)

    native.genrule(
        name = name,
        srcs = [
            unsigned_android_binary,
            keystore,
        ],
        tools = [
            "@androidsdk//:apksigner",
        ],
        outs = [
            output_name,
        ],
        cmd = """
         $(location @androidsdk//:apksigner) sign \
            --ks $(location {}) \
            --ks-key-alias {} \
            --ks-pass pass:{} \
            --v1-signing-enabled true \
            --v1-signer-name CERT \
            --v2-signing-enabled true \
            --out $(location {}) \
            $(location {})
        """.format(keystore, alias, password output_name, unsigned_android_binary),
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough stackoverflow reputation to comment on Steren's answer, but the fist part of the  answer is not correct. Bazel does support signing APKs. In fact every build of an android_binary produces a signed APK, however it is signed with a hard coded debug key.

Bazel intentionally does not provide a mechanism for users to specify a key, because Bazel should not be used to sign with release keys. That would require that your release key is in your workspace, and thus would likely get checked into source control. That would be very bad practice.

Comment: Yes, you are right, check the release keys into the repository is not a good practice.